# Jquery, amend appropriate html element when form is submitted asynchronously

Tags: html, jquery

[UPDATE] I have changed the html code to reflect the answer
in the html I replaced:

```
var cartItemPrice = $("td#cart_item_price")
```

With:

```
var cartItemPrice = $("#"+data.cart_item_id+" #cart_item_price")
```

The tr tag has the product id as its own ID making each one unique

[Question]
I am trying to update all the totals in the cart when ever you update the quantity of a particular product.
So far I can update the Total, Vat/Tax, Subtotal.
However I am struggling to amend the total price for that specific product, which currently sits between TD elements.
I have given the element an id of "cart_item_price" and select them as you would in jquery
However when I update the quantity of one product, If I multiple products all the values are changed 
Suggestions welcome, code is below:

Javascript

```
var formData = $(".form-product-ajax")
formData.on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var thisForm = $(this)
        var cartSubmitBtn = event.originalEvent.submitter.attributes[3].value;
        var url = '/cart/update/'
        var method = 'POST'
        var data = thisForm.serialize();

        if(cartSubmitBtn == "cart_item_update"){
            data = data+"&"+cartSubmitBtn+"=true"
        }
        upDateOrder(url, method, data, thisForm)
    });

    function upDateOrder(url, method,formData, thisForm){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: method,
            data:formData,
            success: function(data){
                var submitSpan = thisForm.find(".submit-span")
                var cartItemPrice = $("#"+data.cart_item_id+" #cart_item_price")
                if(data.updated){
                    var cartUpdateSpanTotal = $(".cart-total")
                    var cartUpdateSpanVatTotal = $(".cart-vattotal")
                    var cartUpdateSpanSubtotal = $(".cart-subtotal")
                    cartItemPrice.html(data.price_of_item);
                    cartUpdateSpanTotal.html(data.cart_total)
                    cartUpdateSpanVatTotal.html(data.cart_vat)
                    cartUpdateSpanSubtotal.html(data.cart_subtotal)
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log("error", error)
            }
        })
    }
```

HTML

```
<table class="table cart-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">£</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='cart-body'>
  
    <tr class='cart-product' id="113">
      <th class="product-info" scope="row">1</th>
      <form class="form-product-ajax" method='POST' action='/cart/update/' data-endpoint='/cart/update/' class="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="vqPDBDgCHn27YeOOdZu2Ch3FAGnLLkUfinWrukSEHBQDg99AEbTEg35wz1jEsuga">
        <input type="hidden" name="cart_item_id" value="113">
        <td><a href="/products/Hat/">Hat</a>
        </td>
        <td>20.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="product_quantity" value="5" min="0" max="10">
        </td>
        <td id="cart_item_price">100.00</td>
        <td><input class='cart-item-product-id' type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1" />
<span class='update-span'>
    <button onclick="this.form.submitted=this.value;" type="submit" name="cart_item_update" id="cart_item_update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="True">Update</button>
    <button onclick="this.form.submitted=this.value;" type="submit" name="cart_item_remove" id="cart_item_remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="True">Remove</button>
</span></td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  
    <tr class='cart-product' id="114">
      <th class="product-info" scope="row">2</th>
      <form class="form-product-ajax" method='POST' action='/cart/update/' data-endpoint='/cart/update/' class="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="vqPDBDgCHn27YeOOdZu2Ch3FAGnLLkUfinWrukSEHBQDg99AEbTEg35wz1jEsuga">
        <input type="hidden" name="cart_item_id" value="114">
        <td><a href="/products/new-mp3/">New Mp3</a>
        </td>
        <td>1.00</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="product_quantity" value="4" min="0" max="100">
        </td>
        <td id="cart_item_price"> 4.00</td>
        <td><input class='cart-item-product-id' type="hidden" name="product_id" value="3" />
<span class='update-span'>
    <button onclick="this.form.submitted=this.value;" type="submit" name="cart_item_update" id="cart_item_update" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="True">Update</button>
    <button onclick="this.form.submitted=this.value;" type="submit" name="cart_item_remove" id="cart_item_remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="True">Remove</button>
</span></td>
      </form>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
      <td><b>Total</b> £<span class='cart-total'> 104.00</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
        <td><b>Vat</b> £<span class='cart-vattotal'> 20.80</span></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
        <td><b>Subtotal</b> £<span class='cart-subtotal'> 124.80</span></td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
      <td><a class='btn btn-success' href='/cart/checkout/'>Checkout</a> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your problem ?

Comment: When I amend the quantity and click update, I get back as the new value: the total price of that item. As well as the total of the whole order (vat,total,subtotal) The problem is that if I have multiple products, I can't amend just the price of that item when its updated. All of them do, hopefully that is clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the selector used are selecting more than one s because those selector finds multiple element matching the criteria.

One solution would be to select those element where you want the change to appear. This can be done using nested selector, For example $(#113 .cart_item_price) . This way you would be selecting only those element which are of interest for the current operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have updated the question to reflect your answer :-)